# Compare two files in unix and awk or perl script

Tags: unix

I am very new to shell script. One production script got deleted wrongly. We need to prepare the script. My requirement is as below.

I have to compare two files, file1 and file2. Each file has 56 columns separated by `|`.

First column is the employee number in the file, I will check whether same employee number is present in the second file or not. If not we will write the whole row to the output file. If same employee number is present in the file2, I need to compare value of each column. If data doesn't match, we have to write it to the output file.  If values of each column match then we need to omit that record.

```
Sample File
File 1
2620|256034|131021|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||
2622|256034|131021|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||
2623|256034|131021|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||
File 2
2620|256034|234567|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||
2621|256034|131021|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||
2622|256034|131021|Mission Quality|||
2623|256034|131021|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||

Sample Output:
2620|256034|131021|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||
2621|256034|131021|Mission Quality and Wipro Way|||
2622|256034|131021|Mission Quality|||
```

Comment: Take a look at diff utility.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FILENAME=="file1" {arr[$0]++}
     FILENAME=="file2" {if($0 in arr) {continue} else {print $0} }' file1 file2 >newfile
```

This forum is really not meant for fixing your work disasters.  And.  Note: Your specifications seem fuzzy to me. This example writes the file2 record out to the new file.  Which is what you seem to say is needed.

You could also restore your script from backup.